# php mysql update form

Tags: php

There's the code:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];

$sql = "UPDATE emps SET";
$moresql = '';

if(isset($name) && !empty($name)) {
    $moresql .= " name = '$name'";  
}

if(isset($surname) && !empty($surname)) {
    if ($moresql) $moresql .= ',';
    $moresql .= " surname = '$surname'";    
}

if(isset($mail) && !empty($mail)) {
    if ($moresql) $moresql .= ',';
    $moresql .= " mail = '$mail'";  
}

$sql .= $moresql;
$sql .= " WHERE Id = '$id'";
```

In this code i can update for example: name and leave existing values from surname and email or update surname and leave name and email existing values

But I want also at one time, for example: update name and surname and leave email existing value or update surname and email and leave name existing value or update all fields.
how?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: update name and surname and leave email existing value or update surname and email and leave name existing value or update all fields in HTML form

Comment: This code does what you ask, this is why the if statements are separate and not a full if/else statement, it allows any combination of the name, surname, and mail values to be changed. So yes, what is the question?

Comment: I think he need to update only the fields that changed...

Comment: One problem you will have is when this is False - `if(isset($name) && !empty($name))` - this will still be True - `if ($moresql) $moresql .= ',';` because you have `$moresql = '';` so `if ($moresql)` will always be True. So you could end up with `UPDATE emps SET, surname = '$surname' WHERE Id = '$id'` OR `UPDATE emps SET, surname = '$surname', mail = '$mail' WHERE Id = '$id'` OR `UPDATE emps SET,  mail = '$mail' WHERE Id = '$id'`. The leading `,` will cause the `sql` to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form action="settings.php" method="POST">
       <input type="text" name="full name" />
       <input type="text" name="email" />
       ........ (and more)
</form>

<?php
  if($_POST)
  {
   if(isset($_POST['full name'])) { //Update full name of user and redirect to the settings page on success. }
   else { //Redirect and show errors! }
   if(isset($_POST['email'])) { //Update email of user and redirect to the settings page on success. } 
   else { //Redirect and show errors! }      
  }
?>
```

Or you can use array function of PHP to set the MySql queries in it like ---

```
<?php
  mysql_query("
    UPDATE table name SET 
    //Loading different values from the array using foreach() php function.
  ");
?>
```

similar and useful:

```
if(isset($_POST['foo']) && !empty($_POST['foo'])){/*do stuff*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET ... name=name, email=email
```

In such way table will keep previous values (col_name=col_colname)

in PHP

```
if(isset($mail) && !empty($mail)) 
{
    if ($moresql) $moresql .= ',';
    $moresql .= " mail = '$mail'";  
}
else
{
 if ($moresql) $moresql .= ',';
    $moresql .= " mail = mail"; 
}
```